# Error in Simple PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to make a game using Python, so this is the code:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# 3 - Load images
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png") 

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
        for y in range(height/grass.get_height()+1):
          screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
       screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
       screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
       screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
       screen.blit(castle,(0,345 ))
       screen.blit(player, (100,100))
       # 7 - update the screen
       pygame.display.flip()
       # 8 - loop through the events
       for event in pygame.event.get():
       # check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
         # if it is quit the game
         pygame.quit() 
          exit(0)
```

This is the error I am getting, but I can't figure out how to solve it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/Game 1/game.py", line 19, in <module>
    for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: width/grass.getwidth() is returning a float it seems. Try casting it to an int to see if that alleviates your problem. 
for x in range(round(width/grass.get_width()+1)):

obviously, you should be rounding either up or down depending on your needs.

Comment: `range()` expects an `int` argument, while in your case gets a `float` produced by `width/grass.get_width()+1`.

Comment: Ah come to think of it, round() returns a float it seems. use int() to see if you get the behaviour you want.

Comment: and fix your indentation, it seems that all your while code is in the first for loop

Comment: Thank you, using the int() worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range function requires integers not floats or strings, floats can be converted to integers by using the `int()` function

So instead of:

```
for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
```

use:

```
for x in range(int(width/grass.get_width()+1)):
```

eg:

```
print int(5.145)
>>> 5
```